# Comparing two images - python, openCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Which is the best way to compare two images from same domain, different features in python. Histogram or Image quality functions ?

I have two images for different scenes, the contents inside the images are different, but both of the images are taken during morning.

I want to compare how much these two images are related to each other ?, like my important metric, is to say that these two images were taken during morning for example, even if different contents.
Any idea or way how to do this ?

Comment: Interesting project, but not a suitable question for SO, sorry. This is a research question, not a question that can be answered in a few minutes by anyone here. Unless you’re happy with an obvious pointer such as “use deep learning”. :)

Comment: Hello Cris, yes I know somehow that it is not an easy question, and it's not something which is answered in couple of lines code, and even so, it won't give reliable results.
What I just wanted to know from someone expert with image processing somehow, what could be the closest way to be able to make a comparison. Because for example, if we did image difference, this will mostly be concentrated in showing the difference between what is inside the images (from contents), you get my point ?

Comment: Yes, I get your point. This is why I say that this is a big research question. This is not trivial to solve and will require a lot of experimentation to find a viable solution. Since deep learning, there actually is a path forward, I don’t think you can do this with any of the classical tools. There are no features you can measure in the image that will correlate with the time of day, and not with the scene imaged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy answer to your question.  It depends on how do you consider images similar or different. And this is a subjective measure that is totally dependable on what do you want to do with this information.

Anyway, for this kind of problems, opencv is your friend. Here I list some ideas:

- use histograms: cv2.histogram https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/db7/tutorial_py_histogram_begins.html

with histograms you can know how blueish, greenish or redish an image is. You can compare if 2 images are in the same range (bin) of a specific color. This is something very common when you want to detect skin color.

- if you have an specific object that appears in different images, use SIFT or SURF.